# jQuery without adding additional plugins: trigger event when an element with a specific class is added to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

With jQuery: I want to listen for when an element with a specific class gets added to the page.  When this event happens, I do some logic (represented by an alert message in this example).

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $(this).after('<p class="foobar">Element added</p>');  
});



//Doesn't work, but shows what I am going after. I want to listen for when a p element with the class 'foobar' gets added to the DOM.  When this happens: I want to be able to throw an alert.

//  $('p.foobar').on('when_it_is_added', function(){
//    alert("I have been added to the dom");
//  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>click to add a p element </button>
```

The key detail is that I need the event listener on this dynamic `<p>` element, and I need the event to fire once it is loaded in the DOM.

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/mutationobserver-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way to accomplish this is just by creating your own event and trigger it yourself after you append  **"p"** element to the dom ... or simple execute another function after appended to dom .

**Example 1 :**

```
//Here I'm going to create an event 'tagAdded' and trigger it after appending element..

$('button').on('click', function(){
  $(this).after('<p class="foobar">Element added</p>').trigger('tagAdded');  
});
```

then

```
$('button').on('tagAdded', function(){

//do something

})
```

**OR**

Call method after append..

**Example 2 :**

```
$('button').on('click', function(){

  $(this).after('<p class="foobar">Element added</p>');

  someMethod();
});

function someMethod(){
var newPtAG = $('body').find('.foobar');

}
```

link: http://codepen.io/theConstructor/pen/GqpQqY

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  This would work if I was the one that dynamically added the elements.  However: I used a library and it adds the elements dynamically for me.  Because of this I cannot find a way to say "wait until the element is added, and then call `trigger` ".  The library I used is: https://github.com/ncri/nested_form_fields